# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns

Tags: mysql, sql

quiero conseguir la posición que ocupa un registro determinado de la tabla artículos de una base de datos,
en Mysql el siguiente código funciona,

```
SELECT RowNr
 FROM (
   SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNr,
        articulo
   FROM articulos
 ) sub
 WHERE sub.articulo ='b5'
```

Lo implemento en PHP:

```
 $posicion=DB::select("SELECT RowNr
 FROM (
   SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY articulos.id) AS RowNr,
        articulo
   FROM articulos
 ) sub
 WHERE sub.articulo ='b5'  ");
```

Y me arroja el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: SELECT RowNr FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY articulos.id) AS RowNr, articulo FROM articulos ) sub WHERE sub.articulo ='b5' )
```

Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Creo que eso es Laravel. Y creo que debes usar `selectRaw` para poder ejecutar esa consulta. O en su defecto `DB::raw();`

Comment: @gaidyjg pero el error no esta vinculado con el método de Laravel que use sino con una inconsistencia a nivel de SQL, además un `DB::select` es perfectamente válido

Comment: Ya lo vi. Estás usando un método que es para "contar" como el count y no agrupas tu resultado. Después de tu segundo SELECT haz `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY articulos.id) AS RowNr, articulo FROM articulos GROUP BY id`. Eso debería funcionar o arrojarte un error distinto. El problema es que mandas a contar con otra columna, en este caso **articulos*

Comment: @gaidyjg He cometido un error al pulsar la utilidad de tus comentarios y la verdad es que agrega algo útil ¿Podrías reenviármelos?  Por favor.

Comment: @betaM He cometido un error al pulsar la utilidad de tus comentarios y la verdad es que agrega algo útil ¿Podrías reenviármelos? Por favor.

Comment: Pues lo único que te había dicho, y creo que al igual que @BetaM que debes hacer un group by en tu segunda consulta select, es decir, algo como esto: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY articulos.id) AS RowNr, articulo FROM articulos GROUP BY id`